# fetch not working in service worker

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

i tried to use the fetch event in service worker
but he didnt work for me.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Activated', event);
  fetch('/embed_testing/notification/main.js').then(response => 
          function () {
              console.log(response)
          });
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log("heyyyo");
  if (event.request.url === new URL('/', location).href) {
    event.respondWith(
      new Response("<h1>Hello!</h1>", {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
      })
    )
  }
});
```

any ideas why it is not working ?

Answer (score 3):

A `fetch()` request made from inside a service worker won't trigger that same service worker's `fetch` event handler. (If it did, you can easily imagine scenarios in which you got into a recursive loop.)

If you need to quickly test that your `fetch` event handler is working, which appears to be what you're doing in this case, the easiest approach is probably to just open the JavaScript console in DevTools and manually perform a `fetch('/path/to/whatever')`. A `fetch()` made from inside the JavaScript console will trigger a service worker's `fetch` event handler.

If you're interested in something that's not just a test, but rather sharing logic that's implemented inside of a `fetch` event handler with code that runs outside of the handler, then the recommended approach would be to refactor the code into a standalone function, and then call that function from both inside the `fetch` event handler and from wherever else in your service worker that it's relevant.

Comment: you can give me an example how to use fetch in service worker t oget a js in my project ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If I had to guess, maybe you're talking about how to import an external JavaScript file into your service worker, so that you can make use of it in your global scope? If that's the case, then you want to use the [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) method, which will synchronously request and evaluate an external script.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are testing your app in chrome, try to uncheck flag "bypass for network" in dev tools on the "Application" tab (choose "Service workers" on the left side)